# Android TabLayout Text Sizes being Overwritten on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, android-tablayout

So I was able to successfully modify what my text tabs look like by using the following code, and it looks as expected on most devices including my Nexus

Styles:

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/whiteTransparent</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

The problem is that on Samsung devices (S5 and S7 have been tested) the sizes appear to be overwritten so that they expand or shrink based on the length of text in the tab - i.e. short strings are made larger to filler the space.

I've seen no mention of this anywhere and can't seem to make the device respect my choice to set the text to the same size no matter the length of the tab title.

Any advice on how to stop Samsungs doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In Samsung phones there is an option called font size change in settings.

Always use dp instead of sp so that text size is set based on density pixel.

ur value in dp

u can check the same by playing around font size change in settings of ur samsumg phone

Comment: I've had a go at using dp instead of sp but the same thing occurs. I don't know that I'd say "always use dp" since that would make all text far less accessible for people who increase their font sizes, right?